# Disable buttons on start of AJAX and enable on complete in jQuery datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, button, datatables

Is it possible to disable the "Create" button on start of an AJAX request (as soon as the button is pressed) and enable when the server responds i.e. on complete to prevent possible double submits?

[image]

The button appears while creating a new entry.

```
<button class="btn" tabindex="0">Create</button>
```

The same button appears while updating and deleting an existing entry / row. The same should happen with those buttons too.

- https://editor.datatables.net/examples/inline-editing/simple

Answer (score 0):

Well you could keep an attribute in your button for this. For an example

```
<button class="btn" tabindex="0" data-clicked="false">Create</button>
```

Use the jQuery on `ajaxStart` to change the data value of the button to true. Then in your click event, handle that data value prior to executing the rest of the code.

```
$(document).on( 'click', 'button', function (e) {
    if($(this).data('clicked') == true){
       return false.
    }
} );
```

**Update ::**

The datatable events page for editor provides all of the callbacks for the editor. You could use the `initComplete` event to set the data attribute to button. Then update the `callback` for the click event and handle it there. See the events page for necessary events.

[Editor events](https://editor.datatables.net/reference/event/)

Comment: The button is generated dynamically by the plugin. So, we don't have a control over the button to add an attribute to the button.

Comment: Do you have control over `ajax-call` ?

Comment: Yes you have control over the ajax but would have to override the defaults and write your own. see : https://editor.datatables.net/examples/advanced/localstorage.html

Comment: @Tiny I've edited my question as per your concerns! I hope you get the intended results

Answer (score 0):

You say you want the button to be disabled:

> at the start of an AJAX request (as soon as the button is pressed)

This makes me believe that you mean the `create` button in the form that opens up (pictured in your post) and not the button that brings up that form. However, DataTables should automatically close that form when you hit the create button, and generally the only reason why it wouldn't is that you are getting some kind of error under the hood that is not obviously breaking the webpage. I'd take a look at your browser console and ensure you aren't getting any JS or DataTables errors.

I'd also use something like Fiddler to make sure that the format of the JSON sent to and from the server is what you are expecting, as this is a common source of DataTables errors (and one that I have personally experienced).

Note that in the example page you linked, the form disappears immediately when the `create` button is pressed, stopping the user from double-submitting data.